# How to get the height and width of the image placed in a custom cell in ios

Tags: ios, ios-4.2, ios4

I have a custom cell,and it has a image in it..and I am accessing that image in this way
in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 [[tableCell specialImage] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"One.png"]];
}
```

**So now I want to know how can i get the hieght and width of this "special image"..**

Waiting for your reply

Comment: Refer this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249664/iphone-how-get-the-height-and-width-of-uiimage)

Comment: thanks Saran,,for ur quick reply..i will go through it

Comment: but saran thats not working..

Comment: Check my answer, may be it what you are searching

Answer (score 2):

I think you are searching for that size:

```
CGRect size = [tableCell specialImage].bounds.size;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, I'd expect the following to work:

```
 CGSize specialImageSize = [[tableCell specialImage] size];
```

If that doesn't work, you'll need to post more code for more help. For example, if the above doesn't work, it'd be helpful to know more about what I assume is a UITableViewCell subclass pointed to by `tableCell`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code:

```
UIImage *imageThatIsSpecial = [UIImage imageNamed:@"One.png"];

NSLog(@"Image height is %f and its width is %f",imageThatIsSpecial.size.height, imageThatIsSpecial.size.width);

[[tableCell specialImage] setImage:imageThatIsSpecial];
```