# unwanted distortion: Core image filter is  rotating my image

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, image-processing, core-image

When I run core Image filters, like CIHueAdjust, on some images, they are unexpectedly rotating 90 degrees - counter clockwise. This distortion seems to only happen with images taken with an iOS device while in portrait orientation.

Here is a simple xcode project that features image import and the CIHueAdjust filter: 
[owolf.net/uploads/StackOverflow/HueAdjustProject2.zip](http://owolf.net/uploads/StackOverflow/HueAdjustProject2.zip)

If I run the filter on a portrait oriented image taken with the iPhone ([like this one linked here](http://owolf.net/uploads/StackOverflow/JayFai.JPG)), the results are like the screen capture below.

Is there a fix for this?? Thanks for reading.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image has different orientation. After applying the filter you lose the orientation. You should compensate the orientation with simple affine transformation.

Comment: Wouldn't the proper solution be to copy the orientation property from the original image to the hue adjusted one?

Comment: Or can I just ignore the orientation information in the first place somehow?

Answer (score 2):

```
if ([image imageOrientation] == 3) {
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0);
} else if ([image imageOrientation] == 2) {
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI / 2.0)*-1);
}  else if ([image imageOrientation] == 1) {
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);    
}else {
    //no rotation necessary    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use function UIIMage.FromImage with 3 params (CIImage, scale, Orientation = Right) to rotate the image back to the original orientation. Here is the code snippet:

```
var rotatedCIImage = imageEffectFunc (src); //rotatedCIImage = your CIImage after taken effect that has been rotated 90° counter clockwise.

if (rotatedCIImage != null) {
   UIImage result = UIImage.FromImage(rotatedCIImage,1.0f,UIImageOrientation.Right);
   return result;
} else {
   return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same undesired rotation issue.

I solved it by remembering whether the height of the UIImage getting filtered was greater than the width prior to applying the filter.

After applying the filter, I again checked to see if the UIImage height was still greater than the width.  If it wasn't I rotated the UIImage 90 degrees.

I made use of an extension here to rotate the UIImage after it was determined that the filter had rotated the image. :
[Rotating UIImage in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092354/rotating-uiimage-in-swift)

I used this example to get the UIImage height and width both before applying the filter, and after applying it : 
[iphone - how can i get the height and width of uiimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249664/iphone-how-can-i-get-the-height-and-width-of-uiimage)

My code that did the correction is shown below :

```
if heightIsLargerThanWidth && slideShowImageView_2.image!.size.height < slideShowImageView_2.image!.size.width
{
    self.slideShowImageView_2.image = self.slideShowImageView_2.image?.rotate(radians: .pi/2)
}
```

Note heightIsLargerThanWidth contains a boolean indicating the state prior to applying the filter.