# Rotating UIImage in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm using Xcode 6.0.1 with Swift. I have a UIImage, and I would like to make another image using the old image as a source, with the new image being rotated in some way... say flipped vertically.

This question was already answered [a few months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965638/how-to-flip-uiimage-horizontally-with-swift). However, that solution doesn't work for me, even though the situation is identical.

When I have

```
var image = UIImage(CGImage: otherImage.CGImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: .DownMirrored)
```

Xcode complains that there's an "Extra argument 'scale' in call". After checking with the Apple documentation, this makes no sense, as that version of the initializer does take those three arguments. Leaving out the scale and orientation arguments does fix the problem, but prevents me from doing the rotation.

The only other reference to this that I can find is [this guy](https://github.com/acani/Chats/issues/43), who had the same problem.

What do you think?

I do need this to run on this version of Xcode, so if there's an alternate way to perform the rotation (I haven't found one yet) that would be useful.

Comment: Xcode 6.0.1 is outdated (don't know if that is the problem). Your code compiles without errors or warnings in my Xcode 6.1. Only if you omit the `.CGImage` (as in the referenced github page) then you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: You can rotate the image view drawing the image easily if you like in this Q/A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882487/how-to-rotate-image-in-swift-3#40882640

Answer (score 145):

## Swift 5 Solution

I wrote [Pixel SDK](https://www.pixelsdk.com) which offers a more powerful solution to this problem, otherwise here is the simplest solution:

```
extension UIImage {
    func rotate(radians: Float) -> UIImage? {
        var newSize = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.size).applying(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(radians))).size
        // Trim off the extremely small float value to prevent core graphics from rounding it up
        newSize.width = floor(newSize.width)
        newSize.height = floor(newSize.height)
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, self.scale)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        
        // Move origin to middle
        context.translateBy(x: newSize.width/2, y: newSize.height/2)
        // Rotate around middle
        context.rotate(by: CGFloat(radians))
        // Draw the image at its center
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: -self.size.width/2, y: -self.size.height/2, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))
    
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return newImage
    }
}
```

and to use this solution you can do the following

```
let image = UIImage(named: "image.png")!
let newImage = image.rotate(radians: .pi/2) // Rotate 90 degrees
```

Comment: this is a great solution. I used another one which cutted my image after rotation, but this one works perfect.

Comment: Be careful when dealing with UIImages with different orientations. self.draw() will automatically draw the image with .up orientation.

Comment: I'm using this try to rotate a uiimage in a custom annotationView. the image is a .png of a motorbike. its not rotating the image ... its just returning a black square?

Comment: `.pi` is 180 deg, `.pi/2` is 90 deg, `.pi/4` is 45 deg, ..., `.pi/180` is 1 deg.

Comment: Good answer. you saving my day!!

Comment: If you use SwiftUI, import SwiftUI into your UIImage extension instead of UIKit, and change the function signature to: `rotate(angle: Angle)`. Inside the function, do: `let radians = angle.radians`. Now you can call the function with: `image.rotate(angle: .degrees(90))` or `image.rotate(angle: .degrees(-90)`

Comment: Beware of the force unwrap on `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`, it can be nil and hence cause your app to crash (happened to me, rarely, but still).

Answer (score 48):

Here is a simple extension to UIImage:

```
//ImageRotation.swift

import UIKit

extension UIImage {  
    public func imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: CGFloat, flip: Bool) -> UIImage {
        let radiansToDegrees: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
            return $0 * (180.0 / CGFloat(M_PI))
        }
        let degreesToRadians: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
            return $0 / 180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)
        }

        // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
        let rotatedViewBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))
        let t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(degrees));
        rotatedViewBox.transform = t
        let rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size

        // Create the bitmap context
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
        let bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
        CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width / 2.0, rotatedSize.height / 2.0);

        //   // Rotate the image context
        CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, degreesToRadians(degrees));

        // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
        var yFlip: CGFloat

        if(flip){
            yFlip = CGFloat(-1.0)
        } else {
            yFlip = CGFloat(1.0)
        }

        CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, yFlip, -1.0)
        CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-size.width / 2, -size.height / 2, size.width, size.height), CGImage)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage
    }
}
```

([Source](http://blog.ruigomes.me/how-to-rotate-an-uiimage-using-swift/))

Use it with:

```
rotatedPhoto = rotatedPhoto?.imageRotatedByDegrees(90, flip: false)
```

The former will rotate an image and flip it if flip is set to true.

Comment: confile, flipping works awesome. The problem with the rotation is that is does rotate the image, BUT - it changes the aspect ratio and "destroy it",can you check it and modify the code? it would be great. thanks!

Comment: also find it modifies ratio - so close!

Comment: `ImageView.tintColor` stops working after rotating the image with this function. Even if I try to reset `imageWithRenderingMode` to `AlwaysTemplate`. Any idea why?

Comment: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize) ` should be `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rotatedSize, false, self.scale)` to preserve scale

Comment: @adrum, that was perfect! Mine was pixelating, but was fixed after using your replacement suggestion!

Comment: Works for me, a nice copy and paste solution.

Comment: Xcode gives suggestions to convert this code for Swift 3 except for this line, `CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-size.width / 2, -size.height / 2, size.width, size.height), CGImage)`.  Change it to `bitmap?.draw( cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: -size.width / 2, y: -size.height / 2,width: size.width,height: size.height))`

Comment: Got an error `CGBitmapContextCreate: invalid data bytes/row: should be at least 7680 for 8 integer bits/component, 3 components, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst.` Anyone knew this error?

Comment: This way does not release memory. It keep around 30MB Ram every time I rotate a new photo taken with iPhone 6.

Answer (score 36):

```
extension UIImage {
    struct RotationOptions: OptionSet {
        let rawValue: Int

        static let flipOnVerticalAxis = RotationOptions(rawValue: 1)
        static let flipOnHorizontalAxis = RotationOptions(rawValue: 2)
    }

    func rotated(by rotationAngle: Measurement<UnitAngle>, options: RotationOptions = []) -> UIImage? {
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return nil }

        let rotationInRadians = CGFloat(rotationAngle.converted(to: .radians).value)
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotationInRadians)
        var rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.size).applying(transform)
        rect.origin = .zero

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: rect.size)
        return renderer.image { renderContext in
            renderContext.cgContext.translateBy(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
            renderContext.cgContext.rotate(by: rotationInRadians)

            let x = options.contains(.flipOnVerticalAxis) ? -1.0 : 1.0
            let y = options.contains(.flipOnHorizontalAxis) ? 1.0 : -1.0
            renderContext.cgContext.scaleBy(x: CGFloat(x), y: CGFloat(y))

            let drawRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: -self.size.width/2, y: -self.size.height/2), size: self.size)
            renderContext.cgContext.draw(cgImage, in: drawRect)
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
let rotatedImage = UIImage(named: "my_amazing_image")?.rotated(by: Measurement(value: 48.0, unit: .degrees))
```

With flipped flag specified:

```
let flippedImage = UIImage(named: "my_amazing_image")?.rotated(by: Measurement(value: 48.0, unit: .degrees), options: [.flipOnVerticalAxis])
```

Comment: Thank you, great solution. Could you may provide also a solution for flipping an image?

Comment: @ixany I've updated the answer to flip on the vertical axis. Is that what you meant?

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you again! :)

Comment: Here my research ends , Thanks!!

Comment: This function has serious issues. When imageOrientation != UIImage.Orientation.up, the function gives a completely wrong image.

Comment: in order to maintain the size of the rotated image (which might result in clipped image) remove `.applying(transform)`

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 3:**

Rotating to right:

```
let image = UIImage(cgImage: otherImage.cgImage!, scale: CGFloat(1.0), orientation: .right)
```

**Tested in Playground:**

```
// MyPlayground.playground

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view

let otherImage = UIImage(named: "burger.png", in: Bundle.main,
                         compatibleWith: nil)
let imageViewLeft = UIImageView(image: UIImage(cgImage: (otherImage?.cgImage!)!, scale: CGFloat(1.0), orientation: .left)) 
let imageViewRight = UIImageView(image: UIImage(cgImage: (otherImage?.cgImage!)!, scale: CGFloat(1.0), orientation: .right))

view.addSubview(imageViewLeft)
view.addSubview(imageViewRight)
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Why not? Show me your Playground File!

Comment: This needs to be the answer! Thanks for that!

Comment: This does not answer the question, as they were asking for a method to make *another image*.  This solution just uses orientation EXIF data to display the image turned to the right.   So, for example, you can't call this twice to rotate the image 180 degrees.

Comment: @typewrite: you are right, but it helps others to rotate UIImages

Answer (score 10):

'Extra argument in call' generally happens when one of the input types is incorrect.

You can fix your code with

```
var image = UIImage(CGImage: otherImage.CGImage, scale: CGFloat(1.0), orientation: .DownMirrored)
```

Answer (score 7):

**@confile answer updated to Swift 4**

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {

    public func imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: CGFloat, flip: Bool) -> UIImage {
        let radiansToDegrees: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
            return $0 * (180.0 / CGFloat.pi)
        }
        let degreesToRadians: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
            return $0 / 180.0 * CGFloat.pi
        }

        // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
        let rotatedViewBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        let t = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degreesToRadians(degrees));
        rotatedViewBox.transform = t
        let rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size

        // Create the bitmap context
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
        let bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
        bitmap?.translateBy(x: rotatedSize.width / 2.0, y: rotatedSize.height / 2.0)

        //   // Rotate the image context
        bitmap?.rotate(by: degreesToRadians(degrees))

        // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
        var yFlip: CGFloat

        if(flip){
            yFlip = CGFloat(-1.0)
        } else {
            yFlip = CGFloat(1.0)
        }

        bitmap?.scaleBy(x: yFlip, y: -1.0)
        let rect = CGRect(x: -size.width / 2, y: -size.height / 2, width: size.width, height: size.height)

        bitmap?.draw(cgImage!, in: rect)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Do not use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` because it will destroy the quality of your vector, use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`. This is my implementation in Swift 3/4:

```
extension UIImage {

  func rotated(degrees: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {

    let degreesToRadians: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = { (degrees: CGFloat) in
      return degrees / 180.0 * CGFloat.pi
    }

    // Calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    let rotatedViewBox: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    rotatedViewBox.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degreesToRadians(degrees))
    let rotatedSize: CGSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size

    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rotatedSize, false, 0.0)

    guard let bitmap: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), let unwrappedCgImage: CGImage = cgImage else {
      return nil
    }

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    bitmap.translateBy(x: rotatedSize.width/2.0, y: rotatedSize.height/2.0)

    // Rotate the image context
    bitmap.rotate(by: degreesToRadians(degrees))

    bitmap.scaleBy(x: CGFloat(1.0), y: -1.0)

    let rect: CGRect = CGRect(
        x: -size.width/2,
        y: -size.height/2,
        width: size.width,
        height: size.height)

    bitmap.draw(unwrappedCgImage, in: rect)

    guard let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
      return nil
    }

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
  }
```

Comment: How can I use this extension. I try to use it this way: let originalImage = UIImage(named: "image").rotated(degrees: 90) and didn't work.

Comment: What didn't work? Didn't it compile or didn't it work as expected? Are you using a vector?

Answer (score 5):

Try this code, it worked for me:

```
@IBAction func btnRotateImagePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let originalImage = self.imageView.image {

        let rotateSize = CGSize(width: originalImage.size.height, height: originalImage.size.width)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rotateSize, true, 2.0)
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, 90.0 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0)
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -originalImage.size.height)
            originalImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height))
            self.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I converted this to the Swift4 but it is causing memory problem.

Comment: After using  UIGraphicsEndImageContext() memory problem is solved.

Comment: when capture landscapeLeft image then show image is wrong side.

Answer (score 2):

**For Swift 4.2**

```
extension UIImage {


func rotate(_ radians: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let cgImage = self.cgImage!
    let LARGEST_SIZE = CGFloat(max(self.size.width, self.size.height))
    let context = CGContext.init(data: nil, width:Int(LARGEST_SIZE), height:Int(LARGEST_SIZE), bitsPerComponent: cgImage.bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: 0, space: cgImage.colorSpace!, bitmapInfo: cgImage.bitmapInfo.rawValue)!

    var drawRect = CGRect.zero
    drawRect.size = self.size
    let drawOrigin = CGPoint(x: (LARGEST_SIZE - self.size.width) * 0.5,y: (LARGEST_SIZE - self.size.height) * 0.5)
    drawRect.origin = drawOrigin
    var tf = CGAffineTransform.identity
    tf = tf.translatedBy(x: LARGEST_SIZE * 0.5, y: LARGEST_SIZE * 0.5)
    tf = tf.rotated(by: CGFloat(radians))
    tf = tf.translatedBy(x: LARGEST_SIZE * -0.5, y: LARGEST_SIZE * -0.5)
    context.concatenate(tf)
    context.draw(cgImage, in: drawRect)
    var rotatedImage = context.makeImage()!

    drawRect = drawRect.applying(tf)

    rotatedImage = rotatedImage.cropping(to: drawRect)!
    let resultImage = UIImage(cgImage: rotatedImage)
    return resultImage
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to flip the image horizontally or if you need a mirror image of the original image there is a simple way :

This code works for me to flip the image:

```
let originalImage = UIImage(named: "image")
let flippedImage = originalImage?.withHorizontallyFlippedOrientation()
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/2113668-withhorizontallyflippedorientati)

Answer (score 2):

**Tested With Swift 5 Xcode 13**

```
extension UIView{

func rotate(degrees: CGFloat) {

        let degreesToRadians: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = { (degrees: CGFloat) in
            return degrees / 180.0 * CGFloat.pi
        }
        self.transform =  CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degreesToRadians(degrees))
    }
```

}

Just Pass angle in degree

```
myView.rotate(degrees : 90)
```

Comment: This rotates a `UIView` and not a `UIImage`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for iOS 8+ and maintains the image quality. It's two extensions for UIImage.

```
  extension UIImage {
    func withSize(_ width: CGFloat, _ height: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

      let target = CGSize(width, height)

      var scaledImageRect = CGRect.zero

      let aspectWidth:CGFloat = target.width / self.size.width
      let aspectHeight:CGFloat = target.height / self.size.height
      let aspectRatio:CGFloat = min(aspectWidth, aspectHeight)

      scaledImageRect.size.width = self.size.width * aspectRatio
      scaledImageRect.size.height = self.size.height * aspectRatio
      scaledImageRect.origin.x = (target.width - scaledImageRect.size.width) / 2.0
      scaledImageRect.origin.y = (target.height - scaledImageRect.size.height) / 2.0

      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(target, false, 0)

      self.draw(in: scaledImageRect)

      let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

      return scaledImage!
    }

    func rotated(degrees: Double) -> UIImage {

      let radians = CGFloat(Double.pi * degrees / 180)

      var rotatedViewBox: UIView? = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width * scale, height: size.height * scale))
      let t = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radians)
      rotatedViewBox!.transform = t
      let rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox!.frame.size
      rotatedViewBox = nil

      // Create the bitmap context
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
      let bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

      // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
      bitmap.translateBy(x: rotatedSize.width/2, y: rotatedSize.height/2)

      //   // Rotate the image context
      bitmap.rotate(by: radians)

      // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
      bitmap.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
      bitmap.draw(cgImage!, in: CGRect(x:-size.width * scale / 2, y: -size.height * scale / 2, width: size.width * scale, height: size.height * scale))

      let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

      return newImage.withSize(newImage.size.width/scale, newImage.size.height/scale)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
func rotatedImage(with angle: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    let updatedSize = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        .applying(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle))
        .size

    return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: updatedSize)
        .image { _ in

            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

            context?.translateBy(x: updatedSize.width / 2.0, y: updatedSize.height / 2.0)
            context?.rotate(by: angle)

            draw(in: CGRect(x: -size.width / 2.0, y: -size.height / 2.0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        }
        .withRenderingMode(renderingMode)
}
```