# UIImage init with scale in swift says "Extra Argument" Erroneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage

OK. This is whacky. I've checked the various answers above, and [this is the only one that seems to really hit the mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092354/rotating-uiimage-in-swift).

However, there doesn't seem to be an answer.

I am using Swift to create a new [UIImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html), exactly like this (Objective-C version):

```
UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: aCGImageRefAllocatedPreviously scale:aCGFloatScaleCalculatedPreviously orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

That works fine. However, when I try [the same exact call](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/initWithCGImage:scale:orientation:) in Swift:

```
let myImage = UIImage ( CGImage: aCGImageAllocatedPreviously, scale:aCGFloatScaleCalculatedPreviously, orientation:UIImageOrientation.Up )
```

I get a compiler error, telling me that "scale" is an extra parameter.

This is the kind of error that you get when the signature is wrong.

However, it isn't wrong (as far as I can tell).

What I am doing, is creating a tutorial by exactly replicating an Objective-C function in Swift *(I know, I know, Swift is different, so I shouldn't exactly replicate, but, as Bill Murray would say, "Baby Steps")*.

I'm wondering how the heck I'm screwing up.

If I call it with just the image (no scale or orientation), it works fine, but I need that scale.

Comment: Are you sure aCGImageRefAllocatedPreviously is type of CGImage? If not then compiler may give you that error.

Comment: The `aCGFloatScaleCalculatedPreviously` variable could be an issue as well, if it were actually a Double for example.

Comment: You're missing comma before `scale`.

Comment: Yeah, that's because I didn't copy and paste properly. However, I figgered it out.

Comment: I needed to use takeRetainedValue() on the input CGImage. In my other implementation, I had done that prior, and I missed it.

Comment: ... which again demonstrates how useful a (small) self-contained reproducible example would be ...

Comment: <shrug> Whatever. I'm doing my best. I can't paste the whole thing for a number of reasons, one being that I'd get fired if I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I figgered it out. I was a knucklehead.

I need to use [takeRetainedValue()](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_43) on the CGImage, like so:

```
let myImage = UIImage ( CGImage: aCGImageAllocatedPreviously.takeRetainedValue(),scale:aCGFloatScaleCalculatedPreviously,orientation:UIImageOrientation.Up )
```

That satisfies the signature.

Comment: Is it takeRetainedImage() or takeRetainedValue()? – I assume the latter. Please do copy/paste the real code in your question and answers. Otherwise you are wasting your time and that of the readers.

Comment: @Martin R Good point. The problem is that I am working on a work machine that has no internet connection, and turning around and working on this laptop, so stuff is getting lost in translation. I'll fix it. No, it's not wasting time. It's called "legitimate error," and we all do it. I appreciate it being pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this in the playground and was able to get this code to compile:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

let myImage = UIImage(CGImage: nil,
  scale:0,
  orientation:UIImageOrientation.Up)
```

This syntax also works:

```
let newImage = UIImage.init(CGImage: nil,
  scale:0,
  orientation:UIImageOrientation.Up )
```