# Camera only takes pictures in portrait mode

Tags: ios, swift, camera

When I take a picture in portrait mode everything is fine and looks like this:

[image]

in landscape mode it is in the wrong mode and is rotated around 90 degrees. How can I fix that?
Currently, it looks like that in the gallery. It isn't even saved as a landscape picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the orientation from an UIImage like this: `image.imageOrientation`. And then rotate accordingly.

Comment: oh thanks and how would it look like for videos? If I use the AVPlayer?

Comment: Not sure exactly, maybe refer to this question? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243847/avfoundation-avplayer-rotation

Comment: Doesn't work because I can't set the imageOrientation

Comment: If I take a picture in landscape mode the camera stays in portrait mode an so I can see just the picture rotated. How could I rotate it?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645060/rotate-uiimage-in-swift

Comment: I want to save it as a landscape pic if the device was in landscape mode. Currently the picture is saved as a portrait picture every time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118887/discussion-between-mafioso-and-luka-jacobowitz).