# How to display image in Diamond shape in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview

[Original image is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOP9R.png) Hai i am new to iOS my requirement is display images in diamond shape  so for that purpose i followed the following code. I took a UIView and ImageView is subview to that UIView. i am getting diamond shape but image is flipping . how to solve that issue?

[image: check the output here]

```
  var tr: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
  tr = CGAffineTransformScale(tr, 0.8, 1)
  tr = CGAffineTransformRotate(tr, 0.7)
  self.views.transform =  tr
```

Comment: I've posted another answer, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UIBezierPath` to draw shapes

```
import UIKit

extension UIView
{
    func addDiamondMaskToView()
    {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: 0))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width, y: self.bounds.size.height / 2.0))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: self.bounds.size.height))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.size.height / 2.0))
    path.closePath()

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

    self.layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }
}
```

You can call the method as

```
//suppose this is your imageview
let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200))
//then call the method as
imgView.addDiamondMaskToView()
```

Its working fine for me, check the images for reference

[image]

Comment: can u tell me the exact width and height for uiimageview

Comment: Updating the answer wait

Comment: thank you for responding waiting for your positive feedback

Comment: Let me if it helped

Comment: there is lot of difference for your output and my reqierment

Comment: Means, what's the difference? Also if image is looking bigger is because of content mode. What's ur requirements

Comment: i need exact like above image

Comment: but i am not exact output what i need

Comment: Yeah, wait a minute

Answer (score 0):

As you have provided the image, after analysing I can conclude that you need to do is

- Add diagonal mask to the ImageView
- Rotate image inside that imageView to some angle

assuming that the image is rotated to 45 degrees, I'm providing the solution as

```
import UIKit

extension UIView
{
func addDiamondMaskToView()
{
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: 0))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width, y: self.bounds.size.height / 2.0))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: self.bounds.size.height))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.size.height / 2.0))
    path.closePath()

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    self.layer.mask = shapeLayer
}
}

extension UIImageView
{
    func addDiamondWithSomeAngle(angleInDegrees degrees : CGFloat)
    {
        self.addDiamondMaskToView()
        self.image = self.image?.imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees, flip: false)
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    public func imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: CGFloat, flip: Bool) -> UIImage 
    {
        let degreesToRadians: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
            return $0 / 180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)
        }
        let rotatedViewBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))
        let t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(degrees));
        rotatedViewBox.transform = t
        let rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
        let bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width / 2.0, rotatedSize.height / 2.0);

        CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, degreesToRadians(degrees));

        var yFlip: CGFloat

        if(flip){
            yFlip = CGFloat(-1.0)
        } else {
            yFlip = CGFloat(1.0)
        }

        CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, yFlip, -1.0)
        CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-size.width / 2, -size.height / 2, size.width, size.height), CGImage)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage
    }
}
```

You need to call  the method as

```
imageView.addDiamondWithSomeAngle(angleInDegrees: 45)
```

Output is as follows

[image]

Courtesy : [Image rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092354/rotating-uiimage-in-swift) by [confile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055664/confile)

Comment: Great, please accept the solution, and help others also to find the solution

Comment: sure and  i have one more question can i ask it

Comment: Yeah sure, go ahead

Comment: :) , I'll try to answer that question, it may take time to achieve that. You first accept this question :)

Comment: No, you need to accept this as correct answer, you need to tick below the up arrow

Comment: Hey bro, You have accept the wrong one, this one is correct answer

Comment: bro i applied the first one

Comment: But i guess, second one is as per your need. Right?

Comment: yeah but when i applied uiview frame through coding i got it

Comment: Ok, thanks, checking your second question. Will get back to you soon

Comment: i am very happy for your responding

Comment: very happy if  i got the solution for second question