# how to get one high quality image including subview image on scrollview

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying image crop tutorial

I want to make app that crop image and add sticker.

subviews are imageview’s subview ( imageview.addsubview(subview) )

**[please check this Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhpEy.png)**

Everything is fine, but I can’t make final image. 
I want to make final image using original resolution but my fuction’s result is too low resolution

I lost 5 days about this

example)

scrollview’s rect 0, 0, 200, 400

imageview size 7680 x 4320

I tried below code.
but result quality is very low. because the resolution is 200x400(scrollview’s rect) .

```
func screenshot() -> UIImage {
    guard let imageview = imageview else { return UIImage() }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.scrollView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    let offset = self.scrollView.contentOffset
    guard let thisContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return UIImage() }
    thisContext.translateBy(x: -offset.x, y: -offset.y)
    self.scrollView.layer.render(in: thisContext)
    let visibleScrollViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return visibleScrollViewImage ?? UIImage()
}
```

please let me know how to high quality resolution final image including sticker subviews

how to get one high quality image using

Answer (score 0):

Using that method, you get an image of what is rendered on the screen.

What you *want* to do is calculate the "sticker" size and placement relative to the scaled image and then combine the images.

You can use this extension to overlay one image on another:

```
extension UIImage {
    func overlayWith(image: UIImage, posX: CGFloat, posY: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let rFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: rFormat)
        let newImage = renderer.image {
            (context) in
            self.draw(at: .zero)
            image.draw(at: CGPoint(x: posX, y: posY))
        }
        return newImage
    }
}
```

Use it by calling (for example):

```
let combinedImage = bkgImage.overlayWith(image: stickerImage, posX: 1000.0, posY: 1000.0)
```

That says "Create a new `UIImage` by overlaying the sticker image onto the background image at `x: 1000, y:1000`"

Remember that you'll need to translate your coordinates... So, if you are showing your `7680 x 4320` image in a `200 x 400` scrollview (not taking any zooming into account here), the on-screen image size will be `711 x 400`. If the user places the sticker at `100, 50`, the *actual* position on the original size image will be:

```
    let scaleFactor = bkgImage.size.height / 400.0
    let x = 100.0 * scaleFactor
    let y = 50.0 * scaleFactor

    // scaleFactor equals 10.8
    // x equals 100 * 10.8 == 1080
    // y equals 50 * 10.8 == 540

    let combinedImage = bkgImage.overlayWith(image: stickerImage, posX: x, posY: y)
```

Here is a basic sample you can try out.

It starts with a background image of `5120 x 2880`:

[image]

and a "sticker" image at `512 x 512`:

[image]

And the result, with the sticker placed at `x: 1000, y:1000`. Top image is original background (aspectFit), middle image is the combined image (again, aspectFit), and the bottom image is the actual size combined image in a scroll view:

[image]

Use this source code to run that example (all code, no `@IBoutlet`):

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {
    func overlayWith(image: UIImage, posX: CGFloat, posY: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let rFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: rFormat)
        let newImage = renderer.image {
            (context) in
            self.draw(at: .zero)
            image.draw(at: CGPoint(x: posX, y: posY))
        }
        return newImage
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let origImageView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return v
    }()

    let modImageView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return v
    }()

    let actualSizeImageView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.contentMode = .topLeft
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return v
    }()

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let bkgImage = UIImage(named: "background"),
            let stickerImage = UIImage(named: "sticker") else {

                fatalError("missing images")

        }

        view.backgroundColor = .systemGreen

        view.addSubview(origImageView)
        view.addSubview(modImageView)

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(actualSizeImageView)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        let sg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            origImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            origImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            origImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            origImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),

            modImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: origImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            modImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: origImageView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            modImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: origImageView.widthAnchor),
            modImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: origImageView.heightAnchor),

            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: modImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: origImageView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, constant: -10.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -10.0),

            actualSizeImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sg.topAnchor),
            actualSizeImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sg.bottomAnchor),
            actualSizeImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sg.leadingAnchor),
            actualSizeImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sg.trailingAnchor),

            actualSizeImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: bkgImage.size.width),
            actualSizeImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: bkgImage.size.height),

        ])

        origImageView.image = bkgImage

        let combinedImage = bkgImage.overlayWith(image: stickerImage, posX: 1000.0, posY: 1000.0)

        modImageView.image = combinedImage

        actualSizeImageView.image = combinedImage

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your kindness answer. I one more thing, I want to make the stickerview can be rotate, zoom. and then the view's transform is changed. how to apply the transform when I call overlaywith() ? is it possible to apply transform?

Comment: @ddaddaddda - that's beyond the scope of your initial question. Here is a good example of rotating a `UIImage`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39804312/6257435 ... as to zooming / scaling, calculate the desired width and height of the "sticker" image and modify the `overlayWith` func to accept that size (width and height) and use `image.draw(in: CGRect(x: posX, y: posY, width: targetW, height: targetH))` instead of `image.draw(at: ...)`