# rotate imageView and its UIImage together

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to rotate imageView and its UIImage together at the same time for better animation behavior
it works well when I rotate for the first time, but when I rotate again the image doesn't change, what am I doing wrong?

```
let imageToRotate =  UIImageView()

@objc func rotateImageButtonTapped() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        let rotatedTransform = imageToRotate.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 2)
        imageToRotate.transform = rotatedTransform
    })
   
    let image = imageToRotate.image

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        let rotatedImage = image?.rotate(radians: .pi / 2)
           page.isRotated = .rotated(rotatedImage: rotatedImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) ?? Data())
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Why are you rotating both the image and the view? Just delete the DispatchQueue block and it should work fine. If it doesn't work, show where you call "rotateImageButtonTapped" in your code.

Comment: `.rotate` is not a `UIImage` method... what is your `image?.rotate(radians: .pi / 2)` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @DonMag I tried to rotate it using this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47402811/9872175

Comment: @FelipeCruzV10 I'm rotating both for better animation, also somewhere in my code I need only the UIImage and it's not accessible if I get it from my imageView 
the "rotateImageButtonTapped" is only a button

Comment: If you rotate just the image view, the animation looks good. What do you mean with better animation? And I ask about the call of the function because I'm trying your code and it rotates good on each click...

Comment: @FelipeCruzV10  thank you for your comment, that's the point it rotates good on each  click, but when I rotate with double click let's say the image 
 was 90 degree and I want it to be -90
the image is still the first rotation click which is 0

Comment: If you want double clicking, you have to target another function to manage it. I understand from what you've said, that a button calls the function on single click.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    let rotatedTransform = imageToRotate.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 2)
    imageToRotate.transform = rotatedTransform
})
```

does ***NOT*** rotate the `UIImage` -- it rotates the image view.

So, when you then do:

```
let image = imageToRotate.image
```

you get the **original** image that you assigned to the image view.