# Xcode UITableView Custom Cell xib Image Height

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Please see this photo and help me, it is very important for me. thank you very much

[image]

Comment: post your relevant code

Comment: In CellForRowAtIndexPath, you will create an UIImageView and increase the cell Height for particular index.

Comment: Create a custom table cell for that. Example at http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: whether the image is from local or web

Comment: i created custom table cell, but image size all same, i have 2 imageview and all image height are different height, so i want to display images with orjinal image size

Comment: Please describe your problem in text form in the question as well. Having the question primarily consist of an image makes this question have almost no future value (which goes against what [so] is about), as Googling for something similar is unlikely to get someone here, as images aren't indexed.

Comment: set cell height according to your image size.

Comment: i do not know how to do that

Comment: what you have tried.. post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to customize the height of the custom cell and also need to resize the image views inside the custom cell according to your image

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

CGFloat cellHeight = image1height + image2height + <button height>;

return cellHeight;

}
```

Also need to assign the imageView rect in the custom cell according to the images dynamically.

Comment: i do not now how get image size,  i added my code please RAJA SAB can you help me to solve this

Comment: there is a porperty to get uiimage size. see this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249664/iphone-how-get-the-height-and-width-of-uiimage

Answer (score 1):

I would implement heightforRowAtIndexPath for this, in short:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//first image height must be fetched for the ccurrent image using indexpath.row...

//Then use the height to set cell height:
    return imageHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1.png", @"2.png", @"3.png", @"4.png", nil];

}


#pragma mark **** TableView ***
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [tableData count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *listTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:listTableIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }


    cell.myImage1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 85;
}
```