# How to get dimension of png file stored in documents folder of iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am facing a problem, hope some one will help me to sort it out. I am working on an application that saves png files in the documents folder of the iPhone application, and also user can view the files that were saved. 
So, i want to know is there any way to find out the dimension of the file being displayed? so that, if image dimension is bigger than my imageView then i can make them scroll, currently image is shrink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may help...

```
ImageIO framework (CGImageSource...)
```

similar Q to [accessing UIImage properties without loading in memory the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169677/accessing-uiimage-properties-without-loading-in-memory-the-image/4170099#4170099)

Comment: I assumed, since the images were being displayed, they be loaded anyway, but this is a good solution

Answer (score 1):

Create a UIImage from the file, using `imageWithContentsOfFile:`. The size of the image is held in the `size` property of your new UIImage object.