# Accessing Image Properties Without Loading the Image Into Memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am attempting to get the *GPS* data from an image that was picked from a `UIImagePickerController`

I am using [this site](https://oleb.net/blog/2011/09/accessing-image-properties-without-loading-the-image-into-memory/) as a reference.

After the the pick the selected image, the `CGImageSourceRef` is always null.

Here is the output from my NSLog

> Info: {
>        UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.image";
>        UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = " size {2448, 3264} orientation 3 scale 1.000000";
>       UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=B01DF2C7-B954-41D8-B3FE-6096706DF3BB&ext=JPG";
>    }
>
> imageFileURL: assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=B01DF2C7-B954-41D8-B3FE-6096706DF3BB&ext=JPG
>
> ImageSource was Null

Here is my code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSLog(@"Info: %@", info.description);


    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            NSURL *imageFileURL = (NSURL*) info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

            NSLog(@"imageFileURL: %@", imageFileURL.description);

            CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef) imageFileURL, NULL);

            if (imageSource == NULL) {
                NSLog(@"ImageSource was Null");
                return;
            }

            NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], (NSString *)kCGImageSourceShouldCache,
                                    nil];
            CFDictionaryRef imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, (CFDictionaryRef)options);
            CFRelease(imageSource);

            CFDictionaryRef gps = CFDictionaryGetValue(imageProperties, kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary);
            if (gps) {
                NSString *latitudeString = (NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(gps, kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude);
                NSString *latitudeRef = (NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(gps, kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitudeRef);
                NSString *longitudeString = (NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(gps, kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude);
                NSString *longitudeRef = (NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(gps, kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitudeRef);
                NSLog(@"GPS Coordinates: %@ %@ / %@ %@", longitudeString, longitudeRef, latitudeString, latitudeRef);
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            }); //distpach get main queue
        });//background queueu
    }];//picker completion

}
```

**I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help?**

Comment: See also: [accessing UIImage properties without loading the image in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169677)

Answer (score 0):

UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL is deprecated.
[You should use UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset instead.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerphasset) Assuming there is a PHAsset for that key in the info dictionary, it should also provide [location data as a CLLocation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phasset/1624788-location)

Edit: Since you said you need to support earlier OS versions, this code worked for me based on what you already have.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
  [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

      NSURL *imageFileURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL];
      CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)imageFileURL, NULL);

      if (imageSource == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"ImageSource was Null");
        return;
      }

      NSDictionary *options = @{(NSString *)kCGImageSourceShouldCache : @(NO)};
      CFDictionaryRef imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, (CFDictionaryRef)options);
      CFRelease(imageSource);

      CFDictionaryRef gps = CFDictionaryGetValue(imageProperties, kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary);
      NSString *latitudeString = (NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(gps, kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude);
      NSString *latitudeRef = (NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(gps, kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitudeRef);
      NSString *longitudeString = (NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(gps, kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude);
      NSString *longitudeRef = (NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(gps, kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitudeRef);
      NSLog(@"GPS Coordinates: %@ %@ / %@ %@", longitudeString, longitudeRef, latitudeString, latitudeRef);
    });//background queue
  }];//picker completion
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to support back to iOS9 and that is only available on iOS 11.

Comment: That sucks. I updated the answer with my solution using something close to your original method. The URL I use is UIImagePickerControllerImageURL instead of the UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL. There's also some syntactic sugar and toll-free-bridging going on.

Comment: Deprecated does not mean it is not going to work. It only means that the API is scheduled to be discontinued in the near future. So using UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL in iOS11 is fine.

Comment: Sorry @Dare this still doesn't work. The ImageSource is still `null`